# How to set a variable in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, variables, cordova, mbprogresshud

I have no idea how to program in Objective C. I'm a Javascript guy. I'm trying to modify this Phonegap plugin and I think I'm 99% there.

In the full code below, if i set `self.progressHUD.progess = .5;` it works great!. But if I set that to the variable `progress` it doesn't compile at all. And Phonegap doesn't give me any compilation errors to go off of.  I don't understand why I can't set this property to a variable.

```
(void)setValue:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
NSNumber* progress = [command argumentAtIndex:0];

if (!self.progressHUD) {
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    return;
}
self.progressHUD.progress = progress;
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@""];
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of `progressHUD.progress`?

Comment: You can't assign a `NSNumber *` to a `CGFloat`.

Comment: What makes it a CGFloat?

Comment: @SeanClark Look at the docs for the `progress` property. Its type is `CGFloat` (or maybe `float`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `progress` property of MBProgressHUD is of scalar type `float`, but your progress variable is an object of type NSNumber. You need to get the raw float value from your NSNumber object; you can do this with the `floatValue` property:

```
self.progressHUD.progress = progress.floatValue;
```

(This is assuming that the object returned by `[command argumentAtIndex:0]` is always an NSNumber; there is no runtime guarantee of this, so it depends on the code that creates the command object to be correct.)

You will often see integral values (int, BOOL, float, and their typedef counterparts NSInteger, CGFloat, etc.) *boxed* as NSNumber or related objects in Objective-C. This is because there are many cases where a data structure (such as NSArray or NSDictionary) only works with pointers to NSObjects. Objective-C provides various ways to box and unbox values.

Comment: 6 hours. 6 hours I spent trying to figure this out. Thank you so much. It never occurred to me that NSNumber was an object where the value was a property. Obvious now..

Answer (score 1):

Try progress.floatValue.  NSNumber is a class cluster, which means that an instance of it may behave as one of several different classes; as such, it's an object which holds a value but that value can be interpreted in a number of ways- you can think of it as being in a sort of indeterminate state. You have to tell it what to convert its value to.

Comment: FYI - `NSNumber` being part of a class cluster is completely irrelevant to the fact that it's an object that wraps a value. And it's not in an indeterminate state. It's in a very specific state actually.

Comment: @rmaddy Of course it isn't in an indeterminate state.  Floats and ints are stored very differently below the hood, as it were.  My point was that when you have an NSNumber, you can't just ask it for a value, because it doesn't know how to interpret its value.  This wouldn't be obvious to a self described Javascript guy, so I was pointing it out without going into detail.

Comment: @rmaddy Does the edit make clear what I meant by indeterminacy?  If I'm still off base about the class-cluster bit, I apologize, it's been a very long time since I've used objective C. I used it back when iMacs looked like aquariums!